# how to get a pie progress bar

Tags: iphone, ios, progress-bar

I like the small pie progress bar like it's in Xcode, when search for a string in the project (Shift-Command-F), see picture.

How can this be called on iOS? I'd love to have it for a download queue.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode searching for a string in a projekt]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can use [SSPieProgressView](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/sspieprogressview)

Answer (score 6):

There's no stock circular deterministic progress view. Here's an example `drawRect:` you might use to implement such a thing.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat circleRadius = (self.bounds.size.width / 2) - (self.strokeWidth * 2);
    CGPoint circleCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
    CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(circleCenter.x - circleRadius, circleCenter.y - circleRadius, 2 * circleRadius, 2 * circleRadius);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    // Draw stroked circle to delineate circle shape.

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.fillColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.strokeWidth);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, circleRect);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    // Draw filled wedge (clockwise from 12 o'clock) to indicate progress

    self.progress = MIN(MAX(0.0, self.progress), 1.0);

    CGFloat startAngle = -M_PI_2;
    CGFloat endAngle = startAngle + (progress * 2 * M_PI);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.fillColor.CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, circleCenter.x, circleCenter.x);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMidX(circleRect), CGRectGetMinY(circleRect));
    CGContextAddArc(context, circleCenter.x, circleCenter.y, circleRadius, startAngle, endAngle, NO);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

You would need to create `strokeWidth` and `fillColor` properties to use this code directly, but it should be a start. [Here's a sample project with a couple of examples.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13103695/AHCircularProgressIndicatorDemo.zip)

Comment: Unfortunately this won't be animatable… I'm struggling with this at the moment

Comment: True, although you could convert this over to draw into a `CALayer` with a custom action to animated the progress property. Definitely an interesting exercise for the reader.

Comment: And exactly what I just did yesterday :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use the code from [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) there is a pie like this in some kind bigger.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe they're released a `UIProgressView` like this on iOS, but you can create it yourself. To put things in the right-hand side of a text view, use the `rightView` property (don't forget to set `rightViewMode` as well).

You can create a custom `UIView` for this (I doubt it'd be worth trying to subclass `UIProgressView`). I would probably hand-draw it with a `drawRect` rather than trying to use images or anything like that. Should be much easier to fill the correct percentage that way.

Comment: [UIView *rightView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW27)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [LSPieProgressView](https://github.com/tinymind/LSPieProgressView)

It's an UIView Category, can show a pie progress overlay any UIView.

Code Example:

```
#import "UIView+LSPieProgress.h"

- (void)updateProgress
{
    [self.button setProgress:self.progress];
}
```